# Length limit to GeoServer SLD files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld

I'm symbolizing a polygon layer by an attribute called `kkod`. I've copy pasted the `FeatureTypeStyle` block about 10 times for each `kkod` but the 11th time the WMS layer is no longer symbolized in QGIS, but it is valid and visible in layer preview in GeoServer.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>tk_my</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>A dark orange polygon style</Title>
     <FeatureTypeStyle>
       <Rule>
         <Name>Vattenyta</Name>
         <ogc:Filter>
           <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
             <ogc:PropertyName>kkod</ogc:PropertyName>
             <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
           </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
         </ogc:Filter>
       <PolygonSymbolizer>
         <Fill>
           <CssParameter name="fill">#bed4eb</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#bed4eb</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>

many more

     <FeatureTypeStyle>
       <Rule>
         <Name>Låg bebyggelse</Name>
         <ogc:Filter>
           <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
             <ogc:PropertyName>kkod</ogc:PropertyName>
             <ogc:Literal>14</ogc:Literal>
           </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
         </ogc:Filter>
       <PolygonSymbolizer>
         <Fill>
           <CssParameter name="fill">#fadaa2</CssParameter>
         </Fill>
         <Stroke>
           <CssParameter name="stroke">#fadaa2</CssParameter>
           <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</CssParameter>
         </Stroke>
       </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
      
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I've looked in the very long log, can it be this that is causing the problem?

```
Request: getServiceInfo
2021-07-15 11:37:15,641 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Rendering request would use 71895KB, whilst the maximum memory allowed is 65536KB
```

Comment: QGIS has no knowledge of the SLD that is stored on GeoServer, it is only fetching an image of your map. So it's more likely to a problem at the GeoServer issue - please look in the log file and see if there is any more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoServer has service limits avoiding the usage of too much memory. Each FeatureTypeStyle makes the rendering engine allocate one more rendering surface, to handle them as Z levels. At 11 of them, the memory limit kicks in and the server refuses to answer your request.

You can adjust it in Services-WMS

Comment: I raised it to 100 MB and the problem was solved